# Stripe collect customer billing address and calculate tax dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

so far I managed to create the form that collects customer credit card information, however, I am trying to find how to add the form that also collects customer address for verification and tax calculation, so far I have not been able how to add the address and postal code like the image below:
[image]

Is this form something that Stripe has built in or the address form are separate from Stripe API?

So far I have checked these links and had no successes:

1. https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object#card_object-address_line1
2. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web
3. https://checkout.stripe.dev/preview
4. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/taxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe does not provide address or postal code fields.  Instead you would add normal HTML form fields on your page with the values being passed in when you call Stripe.js methods like `stripe.confirmCardPayment`.

For example, you can pass in name, email, country, and postal code like this:

```js
stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
        type: 'card',
        card: cardElement,
        billing_details: {
            name: 'Jane Doe',
            email: 'jane@example.com',
            address: {
                country: 'US',
                postal_code: '98765',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Instead of those hardcoded values you can pull the information from the various `<input>` elements on your page.

See [Stripe's documentation for `stripe.confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) for more details, and [Stripe's documentation on Payment Method `billing_details`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-billing_details) for all of the properties you can define here.

Comment: This is where it confuses me. What is the purpose of customer (name, email, phone, address) object for then? Should that be used if it exists when billing details here are missing? customer object has address  as well..

Comment: Customer objects contain details about the customer like their name, email, physical address, shipping address, etc.  Payment Methods have independent billing addresses as Payment Methods can have billing addresses that differ from the Customer's address.  Imagine a single Customer who has a personal card with their home address as the billing address and a second corporate card with their work address as the billing address, for example.

Comment: OK. Yet it seems in the billing details here, there is no way to override or specify the business Tax ID which is part of the customer object. I guess this is by-design. Once you have a business Tax ID or Tax IDs, that applies to all your payments automatically